# Debug Toolbar for ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, django

Is there something akin to the 'Django Debug Toolbar' for ASP.NET (and more specifically ASP.NET MVC).

It's an HTML page overlay that shows total execution time, SQL queries (and time), what views were called... etc.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit late with the answer. The [mini profiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) does just that. You can see it in action at http://data.stackexchange.com (top left corner).

Answer (score 2):

I use a HttpModule like [this one](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/09/07/PerformanceLogging.aspx) to log request performance information.

Answer (score 2):

[Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/):

> The Diagnostics platform of the web
>
> Providing real time diagnostics & insights to the fingertips of hundreds of thousands of developers daily

Live demo: http://play.getglimpse.com/

> Glimpse Heads-Up Display (HUD) is a mini dashboard that pulls out the most important details about a request and displays it at the bottom of your page.
>
> From the HUD, you can dive down into another level of information by clicking on the "G" in the lower right corner. When the Main Panel opens you will be presented with a series of tabs which offer a range of insights into your application.

Core tabs:

- Ajax
- History
- Timeline
- Trace

ASP.NET tabs:

- Cache
- Configuration
- Environment
- Request
- Routes
- Server
- Session

ASP.NET MVC specific tabs:

- Execution
- Model Binding
- Metadata
- Views

EF tabs:

- SQL

Answer (score 1):

If you are using EF, NH or L2S you can check awesome http://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/UberProf . It'll help you with sql queries and will warn you about some bad practices (select N+1, etc.).
[ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) may be useful for you too.
And to measure time on server side try checking the time between OnResultExecuting/OnResultExecuted. This is basically the time to actually render the page in HTML.
On client side you can use Firebug extension to Firefox, check [Network tab](http://getfirebug.com/network)

Answer (score 0):

No, nothing I'm aware of.

If you're using WebForms as your views you can get the name of the rendered view from standard ASP.NET trace (set , then navigate to {approot}/trace.axd). And if you're using SQL Server as your DBMS use Profiler to see queries.